# C# processing received socket data via threads

Tags: c#, xml, multithreading, sockets, multitasking

I have a problem with scalability and processing and I want to get the opinion of the stack overflow community.

I basically have XML data coming down a socket and I want to process that data.  For each XML line sent processing can include writing to a text file, opening a socket to another server and using various database queries; all of which take time.

At the minute my solution involves the following threads:
Thread 1
Accepts incoming sockets and thus generates child threads that handle each socket (there will only be a couple of incoming sockets from clients).  When an XML line comes through (ReadLine() method on StreamReader) I basically put this line into a Queue, which is accessible via a static method on a class.  This static method contains locking logic to ensure that the program is threadsafe (I could use Concurrent Queue for this of course instead of manual locking).

Threads 2-5
Constantly take XML lines from the queue and processes them one at a time (database queries, file writes etc).

This method seems to be working but I was curious if there is a better way of doing things because this seems very crude.  If I take the processing that threads 2-5 do into thread 1 this results in extremely slow performance, which I expected, so I created my worker threads (2-5).

I appreciate I could replace threads 2-5 with a thread pool but the thread pool would still be reading from the same Queue of XML lines so I wandered if there is a more efficient way of processing these events instead of using the Queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A queue<sup>1</sup> is the right approach. But I would certainly move from manual thread control to the thread pool (and thus I don't need to do thread management) and let it manage the number of threads.<sup>2</sup>

*But* in the end there is only so much processing a single computer (however expensive) can do. At some point one of memory size, CPU-memory bandwidth, storage IO, network IO, … is going to be saturated. At that point using an external queuing system (MSMQ, WebSphere*MQ, Rabbit-MQ, …) with each task being a separate message allows many workers on many computers to process the data ("competing consumers" pattern).

---

<sup>1</sup> I would move immediately to `ConcurrentQueue`: getting locking right is hard, the more you don't need to do it yourself the better.

<sup>2</sup> At some point you might find you need more control than the thread pool providers, that is the time to switch to a custom thread pool. But prototype and test: it is quite possible your implementation will actually be worse: see paragraph 2.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your response.  I was going to move to thread pool and ConcurrentQueue anyway. About half an hour after posting my initial message I found message queues and have begun researching AMQP, STOMP, MSMQ etc and the various programs like RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ.  Have you used any message queue programs?  Would you specifically recommend any?

Comment: @user1593436 I have used (or rather used other's wrappers around…) several. But none recently. Given its integration I would start with with MSMQ, but look to build abstractions to avoid locking into any one (this would also allow unit testing by having a fake input queue).